# rembg throws RuntimeError: LoadLibrary failed: onnxruntime_providers_tensorrt.dll

Tags: python, onnx, loadlibrary, tensorrt, rembg

I am not able to generate the image whose background is removed

```
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image

input_path = "crop.jpeg"
output_path = 'crop1.png'

input = Image.open(input_path)
output = remove(input)
output.save(output_path)
```

I have the error as : RuntimeError: D:\a_work\1\s\onnxruntime\core\session\provider_bridge_ort.cc:1069 onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : LoadLibrary
failed with error 126 "" when trying to load "C:\users\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_providers_tensorrt.dll"

Answer (score 5):

This is a onnxruntime package issue. Just reinstalling the onnxruntime will help.

```
pip uninstall rembg //uninstall rembg
pip uninstall onnxruntime //uninstall onnxruntime
pip install rembg[gpu] onnxruntime-gpu //install rembg with GPU support
```